# I want to change the color of the text in a UITextView box

Tags: colors, textview, controls, uitextview

I'm sure there is a simple solution.

I was trying

```
if(segementedControlIndex==0){
myText.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];}
```

it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting textColor on a UITextView works for me.  Are you sure `myText` is not nil?  Did you hook it up to a UITextView in your nib?

Comment: Nah it is not nil. Perhaps I need to bring in the textview delegate :S 
I'm using a segmented control does that affect it?

Comment: I tested with a segmented control and no text view delegate.